# WebGL - Open URL in new tab?

Tags: unity, webgl, browser-based-games, browser

How to open URL in new tab for WebGL?

Tried Application.OpenURL("url"). But it's opens a tab in same window

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.
You don't have any way to set the target attribute from within the player.
The [docs for the OpenURL](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) state

> When executed in the web player, the page the plugin is contained in will be redirected to the url.

I would just assume that it's also true for the webGL player.

But if you took the time to [read the maunual](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html), you could write a simple javascript to open new tabs, and call that from the webGL player.

Your probably getting down voted because this info is readily available.

Comment: thanks dval. I just found this link and solved the problem
http://va.lent.in/opening-links-in-a-unity-webgl-project/

Comment: Looks like they changed. according to the latest Unity docs "From version 2019.4.25f1, 2020.3.5f1, 2021.1.2f1, and 2021.2.0a11, Application.OpenURL opens url in a new browser tab."